# Map DTO to Entity

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core, entity, dto

These are my `Entities`: In this scenario, each user can make a `Post`. Each post can have a list of `Items` and each item can have a list of users that Tagged in it.

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public int LikeCount { get; set; }
    public PostStatuses Status { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("UserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }

    public List<PostItem> PostItems { get; set; }

    public Post()
    {
        PostItems = new List<PostItem>();
    }
}

public class PostItem
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public int PostId { get; set; }
    public long AttachmentId { get; set; }  // Refer to CDN file Id

    [ForeignKey("PostId")]
    public Post Post { get; set; }

    public List<PostItemTag> TaggedUsers { get; set; }
}

public class PostItemTag
{
    public int PostItemId { get; set; }
    public int TaggedUserId { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("PostItemId")]
    public PostItem PostItem { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TaggedUserId")]
    public User User { get; set; }
}
```

These are my `DTO`s:

```
public class CreatePostRequestDTO
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public string Body { get; set; }
    public List<PostItemDTO> PostItems { get; set; }
}

public class PostItemDTO
{
    public long AttachmentId { get; set; }
    public List<PostItemTagDTO> TaggedUsers { get; set; }
}

public class PostItemTagDTO
{
    public int UserId { get; set; }
    public int X { get; set; }
    public int Y { get; set; }
}
```

And this is my API:

```
    public async Task<BaseResponseDTO<bool>> CreatePost(CreatePostRequestDTO createPostRequestDTO)
    {
        Post post = new Post()
        {
            Body = createPostRequestDTO.Body,
            Status = PostStatuses.Posted,
            UserId = createPostRequestDTO.UserId,
        };
        post.Mentions = createPostRequestDTO.Mentions.Select(x => new PostMention()
        {
            Post = post,
            UserId = x,
        }).ToList();

        post.PostItems = createPostRequestDTO.PostItems.Select(x => new PostItem()
        {
            AttachmentId = x.AttachmentId,
            Post = post,
            PostAttachmentType = x.PostAttachmentType,
            TaggedUseres = x.TaggedUseres.Select(c => new PostItemTag()
            {
                UserId = c.UserId,
                X = c.X,
                Y = c.Y,
                PostItemId = ? // My problem is here.
            }).ToList(),
        }).ToList();

        ...
    }
```

How can I solve it?

**Edit:**
Some extra code removed.

**Edit2:**
And also some extra descriptions removed.

Comment: *How can I solve it?* -- What's the problem?

Comment: Please, look at this line: `PostItemId = ? // My problem is here`.

Comment: Not really sure what you are trying to ask? Also, what is BaseEntity?

Comment: You dont need to set IDs, if you put everything into lists of root entity end then Add to repository and SaveChanges, then IDs will be resolved via EF core of course if you have database generated id.

Comment: Thank you @CrazyBaran, I will try it.

Comment: Do you want to use AutoMapper or just write logic for it ? Let me know and I can give you some example

Comment: Both of them if it possible. Thank’s.

Comment: There is no defination for `UserId` in `PostItemTag`. Check whether there is any complier error before sharing us the code.

Answer (score 1):

For model binding with `Automapper`, follow steps below:

1. Install package `AutoMapper` and `AutoMapper.Extensions.Microsoft.DependencyInjection`
2. Add `services.AddAutoMapper(typeof(Startup));` to `Startup.cs`
3. Add `ModelProfile.cs` like

   ```
   public class ModelProfile: Profile
   {
       public ModelProfile()
       {
           CreateMap<CreatePostRequestDTO, Post>();
           CreateMap<PostItemDTO, PostItem>();
           CreateMap<PostItemTagDTO, PostItemTag>();
       }
   }
   ```
4. UseCase

   ```
   public class HomeController : Controller
   {
       private readonly IMapper _mapper;
       private readonly ApplicationDbContext _context;       
       public HomeController(IMapper mapper
           , ApplicationDbContext context)
       {
           _mapper = mapper;
           _context = context;
       }        
       public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
       {
           CreatePostRequestDTO createPostRequestDTO = new CreatePostRequestDTO {
               Body = "B1",
               UserId = 1,
               PostItems = new List<PostItemDTO> {
                   new PostItemDTO { AttachmentId = 1, TaggedUsers = new List<PostItemTagDTO>{
                       new PostItemTagDTO{ UserId = 1, X = 1, Y= 11  }
                   } }
               }
           };
           var post = _mapper.Map<Post>(createPostRequestDTO);
           await _context.AddAsync(post);
           await _context.SaveChangesAsync();            
           return View();
       }        
   }
   ```